# Which algorithm to use for a very simple ranking problem?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, machine-learning-model, ranking, learning-to-rank

Currently, I have a dataset with 10 features that results in a ranking of 4 items, i.e. [1,2,3,4], [4,3,1,2], [3,2,4,1] or any $4!$ permutations that can arise from the ranking.

What algorithms are there to train a model for this? Making it a categorical variable with 24 items seems like a silly way to do this.
Another silly way seems to be to transform the data into something like

```
<$x_1$, $item_1$, 4>
<$x_1$, $item_2$, 3>
<$x_1$, $item_3$, 1>
<$x_1$, $item_4$, 2>
<$x_2$, $item_1$, 1>
$\cdots$
```

and solve it as a regression problem, but that seems silly, since it's not including the semantics of ranking, and because ranking is a discrete function.

I don't need a hefty algorithm, maybe something simple on the level of logistic regression, but unsure what algorithm suits the purpose.

Comment: RankNet and LambdaRank are two of the simplest. Have you tried any of them?

Comment: @Tasos they still mainly neural network methods, right? Is there something simple to deploy from say, `scikit-learn`?

Comment: I would say a regression which predicts a score for each sample: lets say from 0 to 10000, if you can come with a meaningfull one. Then sort the results. Otherwise your first idea with 24 classes may be easier to implement.